# I want the text inside the input box to align properly and start a new line once filled

Tags: html, submit

I am new to HTML and was writing a simple submit type and I am having two stylizing issues.

Issue 1: In this code when I type there's a right sidescrolling effect after the borders are filled, I want the box to expand vertically when it is filled.

```html
<input style="height:auto;width:500px;font-size:12pt;margin:30px;border:2px dashed #f69c55;padding:5px;word-wrap:break-word" 
type="text" name="content"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Issue 2: When I set the height to 100 px I want then to align the text to the left top corner and not in the center.

```html
<input style="height:100px;width:500px;font-size:12pt;margin:30px;border:2px dashed #f69c55;padding:5px;word-wrap:break-word" 
type="text" name="content"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is something called:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```